# stop Jupyter notebook if condition is not met (or proceed if condition is met)

Tags: python, dataframe, logic, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter notebook, and as an initial check, I'd like to count the number of rows in a dataframe and only proceed if it is above a certain number of rows.

I have rows_count = df1.count()[0]
rows_count = df1[df1.columns[0]].count()

I'd like the Jupyter notebook only to move on if this is 100 or more rows.

Comment: So make an `if` statement that checks if the number of rows is at least 100.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @ John Gordon,  Can you provide an example?  I'm looking for functioning code that combines if | count rows <500 |  do not proceed into the next jupyter notebook cell.

Comment: I haven't worked with jupyter, so I don't know what "proceed into the next notebook cell" means.  Hopefully someone else can answer.